# Is there option to convert outputs of row in to new column in linux and delete duplicate entry in row

Tags: command-line

I have a cli output as below,

```
GROUP DEFINITIONS   SERVICE DIMENSION
RESULTSBYTIME   False
KEYS    AWS CloudShell
BLENDEDCOST 0.0000026589    USD
KEYS    AWS CloudTrail
BLENDEDCOST 0.000001    USD
KEYS    AWS Config
BLENDEDCOST 46.921  USD
KEYS    AWS Glue
BLENDEDCOST 355.70735552    USD
KEYS    AWS Key Management Service
BLENDEDCOST 0.10418545  USD
KEYS    AWS Lambda
BLENDEDCOST 0.0000002605    USD
KEYS    AWS Migration Hub Refactor Spaces
BLENDEDCOST 0   USD
KEYS    AWS Secrets Manager
BLENDEDCOST 2.0496788951    USD
KEYS    AWS Security Hub
BLENDEDCOST 0.028892556 USD
KEYS    AWS Service Catalog
BLENDEDCOST 0   USD
KEYS    AWS Step Functions
BLENDEDCOST 0.0000000031    USD
KEYS    AWS Support (Business)
BLENDEDCOST 246.2376324993  USD
KEYS    AWS Systems Manager
BLENDEDCOST 0.000351    USD
KEYS    AWS Transfer Family
BLENDEDCOST 208.8   USD
KEYS    Amazon EC2 Container Registry (ECR)
BLENDEDCOST 0.2636971622    USD
KEYS    EC2 - Other
BLENDEDCOST 325.4630384796  USD
KEYS    Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute
BLENDEDCOST 694.4962624953  USD
KEYS    Amazon Elastic Container Service for Kubernetes
BLENDEDCOST 69.890509083    USD
KEYS    Amazon Elastic File System
BLENDEDCOST 0.0000002652    USD
KEYS    Amazon Elastic Load Balancing
BLENDEDCOST 73.2040001769   USD
```

I'm expecting the output as below,BLENDEDCOST duplicate should be removed and KEYS should come in new row. Convert row into coloumns and duplicate should be removed?

```
AWS CloudShell  0.0000026589    USD
AWS CloudTrail  0.000001    USD
AWS Config  46.921  USD
AWS Glue    355.7073555 USD
AWS Key Management Service  0.10418545  USD
AWS Lambda  0.0000002605    USD
AWS Migration Hub Refactor Spaces   0   USD
AWS Secrets Manager 2.049678895 USD
AWS Security Hub    0.028892556 USD
AWS Service Catalog 0   USD
AWS Step Functions  0.0000000031    USD
AWS Support (Business)  246.2376325 USD
AWS Systems Manager 0.000351    USD
AWS Transfer Family 208.8   USD
Amazon EC2 Container Registry (ECR) 0.2636971622    USD
EC2 - Other 325.4630385 USD
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute  694.4962625 USD
Amazon Elastic Container Service for Kubernetes 69.89050908 USD
Amazon Elastic File System  0.0000002652    USD
Amazon Elastic Load Balancing   73.20400018 USD
Amazon Elastic MapReduce    2.28898852  USD
Amazon Glacier  0.0000000025    USD
Amazon GuardDuty    7.367077065 USD
Amazon Inspector    1   USD
Amazon Location Service 0   USD
Amazon Relational Database Service  388.1651428 USD
Amazon Route 53 0.508976    USD
Amazon Simple Notification Service  0.2022960904    USD
Amazon Simple Queue Service 0   USD
Amazon Simple Storage Service   3.338266835 USD
Amazon Simple Workflow Service  0.0000000015    USD
Amazon Virtual Private Cloud    147.4110373 USD
AmazonCloudWatch    60.12971039 USD
CloudWatch Events   0.000048    USD
CodeBuild   29.71339194 USD
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```bash
sed -z 's/\nBLENDEDCOST//g'
```

or `perl`:

```bash
perl -0777pe 's/\nBLENDEDCOST//g'
```

---

To match your output, you will need to add "Blended cost" to the header and remove second line, and remove the `USD`, e.g. pipe output to:

```bash
sed '1s/$/\BLENDEDCOST/; 2d; s/[[:blank:]]\+USD$//'
```

In total:

```bash
some_command | perl -0777pe 's/\nBLENDEDCOST//g;' | sed '1s/$/\tBLENDEDCOST/; 2d; s/[[:blank:]]\+USD$//'
```

Output:

```
GROUP DEFINITIONS   SERVICE DIMENSION   BLENDEDCOST
KEYS    AWS CloudShell 0.0000026589
KEYS    AWS CloudTrail 0.000001
KEYS    AWS Config 46.921
KEYS    AWS Glue 355.70735552
KEYS    AWS Key Management Service 0.10418545
KEYS    AWS Lambda 0.0000002605
KEYS    AWS Migration Hub Refactor Spaces 0
KEYS    AWS Secrets Manager 2.0496788951
KEYS    AWS Security Hub 0.028892556
KEYS    AWS Service Catalog 0
KEYS    AWS Step Functions 0.0000000031
KEYS    AWS Support (Business) 246.2376324993
KEYS    AWS Systems Manager 0.000351
KEYS    AWS Transfer Family 208.8
KEYS    Amazon EC2 Container Registry (ECR) 0.2636971622
KEYS    EC2 - Other 325.4630384796
KEYS    Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute 694.4962624953
KEYS    Amazon Elastic Container Service for Kubernetes 69.890509083
KEYS    Amazon Elastic File System 0.0000002652
KEYS    Amazon Elastic Load Balancing 73.2040001769
```

---

Very easy alternative with output that should be fairly easy to fix:

```
paste - -
```

Answer (score 0):

With `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -M -o1 -o2 '^KEYS\h+(.*)\nBLENDEDCOST(\h.*)' your-file
```

Or with standard `sed`:

```
sed -n '
  /^KEYS/ {
    N
    s/^KEYS[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\(.*\)\nBLENDEDCOST\([[:blank:]]\)/\1\2/p
    t
    D
  }' your-file
```

(not taking care of *duplicates* as it's unclear from your description what they would look like).